# Сhanging even and odd characters in a string array

Tags: c

It is necessary that in the array 4 elements were selected, in these elements the indices changed 0-2, 1-3, then the next 4 elements were taken and so until the array ends

I tried to use built-in loops, but it didn't quite work out. Either the test was displayed shifted 2 indexes forward, or the first 2 indexes were transferred to the end

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBguC.png)

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HoITk.png)

Comment: Show us your work and the problem you have (by editing the question and adding in some code).

Comment: Please provide us with a minimum reproducible example: text that the people in the community can copy-paste in an editor and run, reproducing your issue. An image in an external link is not enough.

Comment: I see that you are using `gets()`. If you have learned that from your teacher, get a better teacher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without code we can't really help you fix it... but here is a solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char str[11] = "HelloWorld";

    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i += 2)
    {
        char tmp = str[i];
        str[i] = str[i+1];
        str[i+1] = tmp;
    }

    printf("%s", str);
    return 0;
}
```

Output: `eHllWorodl`

Save the current character in a temporary variable, replace it with the next one.

Comment: This code doesn't work when the string length is an odd number. On the last iteration of the loop `str[i+1]` is the NULL terminator which should not be swapped.